# Custom template creation in Google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to create custom template in Google dataflow for live data streaming into cloud SQL?

Answer (score -1):

<strike>No. Google Cloud SQL is not a supported I/O transform. See [Built-in I/O Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/).</strike>

Edit: You may be able to connect to Google Cloud SQL with Apache Beam's `JdbcIO` class. However, the class has been annotated as `@Experimental`. See the [JdbcIO documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html).